# External html file not filling div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried piecing together examples from searches, but can't quite get what I want to do to work. After trying for 3 days, I figured I'd reach out for help.

My goal is to open a hidden div and then load another page (from the same site) within it filling up the entire div. Ideally, I would like to be able to select any number of these external html files and have them load into that hidden div. Right now it is partially working, but the external html is only filling a portion of the div. It does the same thing for my local files.

Basically I would like to click any one of a number of links > open hidden div > load selected link > close and hide div > click different link > open hidden div again > load new link.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 $(function () {
 $('a#linkid').click(function () {
     $('div#pagecontent').html('<object data="http://www.jsfiddle.net">');
     $('div#overlayframe').slideToggle("slow");
 });
 });

<div id="overlayframe">
<div id="pagecontent"></div>
<div id="exitoverlayframe"><a href="#" id="linkid">exit</a>
</div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="linkid">page link</a>

#overlayframe {  
position:fixed;
top:2.5%;
left:2.5%;
width:95%;
height:95%;
z-index:1000;
display:none;
background-color:red;
}
#exitoverlayframe {
position:absolute;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
}
```

The demo provided is just loading jsfiddle into the div. What I'm looking to do is load an html file from the same domain. Not sure if that is important information or not.
[Here is a demo of what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/8GPQm/)

Comment: works for me here. http://jsfiddle.net/8GPQm/2/

Comment: `id`'s should be unique

Comment: you can try **[.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** if its just the html

Comment: @shaunakde Is it filling the entire red container for you? It only fills a small portion for me. Also, the .load didn't work for me as well.

Thanks

Comment: "but the external html is only filling a portion of the div" ,  is this the real problem you are facing ? Also mention the list of browsers you are using .

Comment: @midhun  Yeah, that is the primary issue. At the moment, I can probably get away with just fixing that issue and then work on loading the multiple html pages in the same div after that some more.

Comment: Just style your `object` element, give it `height` and `width`.

Comment: Do you want this http://jsfiddle.net/8GPQm/3/

Comment: @Teemu I tried doing that via css and it had no effect. Do you mean adding that style directly in the object tag?

Comment: @shaunakde YES! I'm obviously not an expert at this, but just glancing at what you did makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: No, exactly what shaunakde has done ...

Comment: object{width: 100%;
height: 360px;} add this in your css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8GPQm/3/)**

The `object` is taking default dimensions.

Add this to your css.

```
object{
    height:100%;
    width:100%
}
```